# ssh login with multi-keys (several users) from the same workstation

Tags: ssh

Basically, as it comes from the title, I'd like to login from my workstation to a SSH server by using different account in different shells. What I'd like to do is to backup all my account from this server to my hard drive by using rsync, but as you know rsync can get a connection if the keys have been generated.

I have already an account set with key for login without pass. What I did was to generate a key on the server and then download it on my ~/.ssh folder. I tried it with another account and I chanced the name of the key. Then I download it in my ~/.ssh...but no way to get it work.

I am not an expert of this stuff. If you would provide any tips or way to set it up I would really appreciate your help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

By default, SSH looks for keys with specific names, namely `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, `~/.ssh/id_dsa` and `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa`. If your key is named something else, SSH won't find it unless you tell it about it. There are two ways to go about this.

The first is to use the SSH client configuration file. Use a `Host` line to match the server's hostname, and then set `IdentityFile` appropriately. For example:

```
Host server1.example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa-server1

Host server2.example.net
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa-server2
```

The second option is to specify the key in the rsync command. To do this you need to use the `-e` parameter to tell rsync what transport to use. This would look something like this:

```
rsync -e 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa-server1' server1.example.com:~/ ~/server1/
```